# How to add a hyperlink into sticky note in ITEXT 5?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have sticky note text comments added using

```
annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(
    stamper.Writer, rect, "Some title",
    "blah blah https://www.google.com blah blah",
    false, "Help"
);
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
```

Is it possible to turn https://www.google.com in the content into a hyperlink that links to the url?

Whats the easiest way to achieve this in iText5?